# Sql Server, Get all Week numbers by a given Year?

Tags: sql-server-2008

is there a way to get all the week numbers by a given year?

Let's say I have the year 2011 and want all the weeks for that year, is this possible?

I am using Sql Server 2008.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/24764)**

```
SELECT DATEPART(wk,DATEADD(wk,t2.number,'2011')) as Weeknumb
FROM master..spt_values t2
WHERE t2.type = 'P'
AND t2.number <= 255
AND YEAR(DATEADD(wk,t2.number,'2011'))=2011
```

Comment: It works but why in this page says 52 weeks for 2013? http://www.epochconverter.com/date-and-time/weeknumbers-by-year.php

Comment: @Uuid it's all about how you want the week display, look in this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/24867, there are sometimes rules that if last week should have 3 or 4 days, if last week don't have 3 or 4 days it counts next year first week.

Comment: @Uuid I found this http://www.epochconverter.com/epoch/weeknumbers.php `Week number according to the ISO-8601 standard, weeks starting on Monday. The first week of the year is the week that contains that year's first Thursday (='First 4-day week'). The highest week number in a year is either 52 or 53.`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SELECT DATEPART(WEEK,GETDATE())` to get the week number of the year, ideally i'd say you need a calendar lookup table to build from.